# A problem about split exact sequences.

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

Let $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow^f M \rightarrow^g M'' \rightarrow 0$ be a exact sequence. Then

If there is a homomorphism $\psi: M \rightarrow M' $ such that $\psi \circ f = I_{M'}$ then there is a homomorphism $\phi : M'' \rightarrow M$ such that $g \circ \phi = I_{M''}.$

Since we have a exact sequence then $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective and $f(M') = g^{-1}(0)$.

I was able to show that $M = \psi^{-1}(0) \oplus f(M')$.

I am having trouble to define $\phi$. I know that for every $x \in M'' $, since g is surjective, there is a $y \in M$ such that $g(y)=x$. Now we have that $y = z + w$, where $z \in \psi^{-1}(0)$ and $w \in f(M')$. I got stuck here, I tried a few paths but no success.

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try just defining $\phi(x)=z$.  (You will have to check that this is well-defined; in other words, it does not depend on the choice of $y$ such that $g(y)=x$.)

Comment: Ok. Let $x \in M''$ and $y,y' \in M$ such that $g(y)=x , g(y')=x$. Let $y = w + z$ and $y'= w'+z'$, with $z,z' \in \psi^{-1}(0)$ and $w,w' \in f(M') = g^{-1}(0)$. I need to show that $z = z'$. 
 We have that $g(z) = g(z') $ (since $x=g(y) = g(z) + 0$ and $ x = g(y') = g(z') + 0$). I don't know how to get $z=z'$.Is this a right path? Thank you.

Comment: Since $g(z)=g(z')$, what can you say about $z-z'$?

Comment: $z-z' \in g^{-1}(0) = f(M')$. But I still don't see how can we get $z=z'$.

Comment: You also need to use the fact that $z,z'\in\psi^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Ohh, I see now. We have $z-z' \in f(M')$, then there is $m \in M'$ such that $z - z' = f(m)$. But $0= \psi (z-z') = \psi (f(m)) = m $ (since $ \psi \circ f = I_{M'}$). Finally,  $z-z' = f(m) = f(0) = 0$. Thank you very much!